# Python FBProphet ValueError: Must pass 2-d input

Tags: python, pandas, facebook-prophet

I'm experiencing an error I can't figure out a solution for. I have 5,000 records I feeding through Prophet but get a ValueError: Must pass 2-d input . shape=(124, 56, 16) error. Any easy fixes, or explanations on what I need to change? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import os 
from fbprophet import Prophet

# Read in File
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\capnb\\Documents\\Sales10.csv')

#Create Loop to Forecast Multiple SKUs
def get_prediction(df):
    prediction = {}
    df1 = df.rename(columns={'date': 'ds','quantity ordered': 'y', 'UID': 'item'})
    list_items = df1.item.unique()

    for item in list_items:
        item_df = df1.loc[df1['item'] == item]
        # set the uncertainty interval to 95% (the Prophet default is 80%)
        my_model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality= True, seasonality_prior_scale=1.0)
        my_model.fit(item_df)
        future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq='M')
        forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)
        prediction[item] = forecast
    return prediction

# Save predictions to dictionary
df2 = get_prediction(df1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2,orient='index')


def flatten(dict_of_df):
    # insert column 'item'
    for key, value in dict_of_df.items():
        value['item'] = key

    # return vertically concatenated dataframe with all the items
    return pd.concat(dict_of_df.values())
df4 = flatten(df2)

df4.to_csv ('C:\\Users\\capnb\\Desktop\\export_dataframe8.csv', index = False, header=True)

print (df4)
```